# Splash Screem Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, ios, aplicación-movil, splash

Estoy queriendo generar un splash screen de un Background que sea una imagen y luego en el medio centrado una pequeña imagen que tengo en formato png, necesito personalizarlo de forma nativa (o la que mas facil sea) estuve viendo varios tutoriales en YouTube de como hacerlo, los sigo al pie de la letra pero ninguno me funciona. (Cuando necesite cambiar el Icono de la app logre hacerlo, pero ese Icono es el que me aparece de splash que NO necesito)

cree un archivo **.xml** con el nombre flutter_native_splash.xml y dentro coloque este codigo que vi en YouTube

```
flutter_native_splash:
  background_image: assets/splash2.png
  image: assets/logo_event.png
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al generar el ****flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create**** como dice en la Documentacion, me sale este mensaje en la consola, pero a la hora de ejecutar la app, no se aplica.

**El Splash Screen deberia quedarme tal que asi**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero sin embargo cuando cambie el Icono tambien cambio el splash que venia predeterminado y queda asi..**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Asegurate de hacer un `flutter clean` y compilar todo nuevamente para que los datos se generen correctamente

Comment: Mi problema principal es que no tengo mucho conocimiento de flutter, estoy trabajando con una app que ya esta creada, vi en la documentación usar  "flutter clean" como dices, pero una vez lo hice me genero muchos problemas en la consola que no sabia que eran y de lo cual tuve que borrar el proyecto y volver a hacerlo.

Comment: @BoliVlogsArchivos cuando haces un flutter clean, posterior a eso debes hacer un "flutter pub get" para poder instalar nuevamente los paquetes, supongo que a esos errores te refieres

Comment: Tenias razon, ahora pude solucionar mi problema, descubri que la nueva vercion de android 12 que utiliza el mismo launcher icon como splash screen, de Android 11 hacia atrás solo muestra una pantalla en blanco, en ambos casos se lo puede modificar con el paquete
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash